# How to fix the delemma in control the gui when user logins in GWTP?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Ok, here is my dilemma:

I got a Header presenter which is the nested presenter. The Customer presenter is the child of Header presenter (ie the Customer presenter was put into a slot of Header presenter).

There is Login Panel in Header presenter.

-**So here is the requirements**:

-Users can not see any Gui of Customer presenter if they have not logged in yet.

-When the user logins successfully then it will visible the Gui of Customer presenter.

-When User refreshes the page, the system will check if the customer logined. If he/she did login, then the system will show Gui of Customer presenter. If he/she has not logined, then prompt an error message.

So here is what I did.

In Header presenter, I have a method `loginedSuccessfully()`, this method will `passUserInfo()` (use `eventBus`) into Customer presenter.

In Customer presenter, I have:

```
private int custID=0;
public void onReset(){
   super.onReset();
   if(custID>0){
       showGui();
   }
   else{
       hideGui(); // the hideGui() has Window.alert("Pls Login");
   }
}
private PassUserInfoHandler passUserInfoHandler=new PassUserInfoHandler(){

    @Override
    public void onPassUserInfo(PassUserInfoEvent event) {
       custID=event.getCustID();
       if(custID>0){
           showGui();
       }
       else{
          hideGui();
       }
    }

};
```

When user refresh the Customer page. The `onReset`will be called, if customer has not logined yet then it won't show Gui & prompt a message.

When user logins by clicking login button then `passUserInfoHandler` will be called & it will show the Gui if logged in ok.

But here is the problem. When user **already logged in** & if I open a new browser Tab & re-open the Customer page, then this time both `onReset` & `passUserInfoHandler` waere called & the page prompts the message **TWICE**. This is not Good.

But why that happened?

This is because the `onReset` was called before the  `passUserInfoHandler` was called. That is why checking gui method was called **2 times**.

I used `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Command() {};` but it didn't work.

Do you know how to fix the problem so that it can meet all the above requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWTP is full fledge architecture. It's also have such API that, you can prevent some presenters from revealing themselves by creating your custom **Gatekeeper** classes. For example, if you want some presenters to be accessible only when the user is logged in you could write the following class:

```
@Singleton
public class LoggedInGatekeeper implements Gatekeeper {  

  private final CurrentUser currentUser;

  @Inject
  public LoggedInGatekeeper (
      final CurrentUser currentUser ) {
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean canReveal() {
    return currentUser.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

Then you simply need to add the **@UseGatekeeper** annotation to the proxy of each presenter you want to protect:

```
  @ProxyCodeSplit
  @NameToken("userSettings")
  @UseGatekeeper( LoggedInGatekeeper.class )
  public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<MainPagePresenter> {}
```

I think you should go for it, instead of write manually stuff. Even once may be your code work. but in feature some new bug will be raise in your code. you can refer this [GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted#Blocking_some_presenters).

Comment: some guys Working for Google don't use GateKeeper to manage Login https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwt-platform/ISF3RwIOfic

Comment: I don't think so. I used it in my product.I did not face such problem.can you give me that link?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwt-platform/ISF3RwIOfic
Christain said "Oh and I forgot to say, personnaly I don't do a round trip each time. Instead I keep the user information the first time, then each time that I need to fetch something from the server, I also check if the user has the right to do it on the server side. That way, I don't need any dispatcher in my gatekeeper and if a hacker try to work around it, the request itself is blocked on the server side (Even though he can see some menu and button, if he can't get any content and do anything, it won't help him that much)"

Comment: I think you misinterpret conversation. The summary of conversation is like Don't write dispatcher call into GateKeeper. he used GateKeeper only. what he said read properly 'I don't need any dispatcher in my gatekeeper' RPC Calling everytime is not good idea.

Comment: but how u manage different userType? Ex : if customer logined then show customer page, but if business user logined then show business page, etc. Meanwhile LoggedInGatekeeper handle only 1 universal login?

Comment: Gatekeeper have method 'canReveal()'. There, you can write code  to check usertype and do redirection accordingly. but This api is not use for redirection page. There you can write any logic whatever you want to execute before reveal presenter.

Comment: Why canReveal alway runs before  "CurrentUser currentUser" has an value (ie not null)? So it alway return false cos CUstomer==null. Then the LoggedInEvent was called & then the currentUser!=null but at his point the cabReveal already called.

Comment: u didn't provide a complate solution so it difficult to understand. Anyway i figured out a way that is to use cookies. "public boolean canReveal() { 
   currentUserID=Cookies.getCookies("userID");
   if(currentUserID!=null) return true; else return false;
  }"